# How to start a Sinatra app using "run"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I tried to use a Gemfile in my Sinatra app, but when I launched my app I got this error:

```
$ ruby config.ru  
config.ru:7:in `<main>': undefined method `run' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Here are my three files:

hi.rb:

```
get "/" do
  "Hello world"
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "sinatra"
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'hi.rb')
run Sinatra::Application
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `rackup` command to start your app.  Or install shotgun gem, that is more convenient for development.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should launch the application with:

```
rackup config.ru
```

Comment: Can you explain why rackup is necessary or shotgun is necessary?

Comment: @gustavoanalytics rackup is the script which runs the first and only executable inside a gem called rack using ruby. That executable is also called rackup. Inside it sets up environment for rack applications and starts your default server.